# Google Doc Spreadsheet Doesn't Wrap Text When Editing

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

When I edit text in a cell, the editor forces all the text to a single line. When I exit the cell it goes back to wrapping just fine, but its annoying that when I double click on the cell it expands it out and puts my cursor at the end of the cell. I would rather it keep it the same and put my cursor in line where I clicked like it does in excel. Here is what I'm talking about:

[image]

If anyone has any ideas on how to get this desired behavior, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The most I've gotten is to prevent the cell to expand to the maximum, doing the wrapper manually (Ctrl+Enter). Upon returning to the cell, the wrap is maintained.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. It just feels like a lot of extra work for something that I think should be a standard feature. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Has anyone made an add-on to correct this behavior? My cell contents tend to be 300+ words that need to be edited regularly, so re-finding the portion I want to edit is too time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Select the wanted cell, Go to the menu-bar : Format > Text Wrapping > Wrap

Comment: Nowadays it's actually Format > Text wrapping > Wrap/Overflow/Clip

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The desired behaviour is to wrap text while editing the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> works and seems to be the only way to wrap text. It would be better to have a WRAP TEXT option in FORMAT options.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The desired behaviour is to wrap text while editing the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and found that it is due to conditional formatting. when I remove conditional formatting, text wrap works fine.